# How to find all the dropped elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
    .dropped
    {
        position: static !important;
    }
    #dvSource
    {
        padding: 5px;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 470px;
        margin-top: 300px;
    }
    #dvSource img {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .one {
        left: 20px;
    }
    .nodrop {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    #dvDest
    {
        background:url(images/line_background.png);
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 110px;       
        float: left;    
        margin-left: 20px;          
    }

    #dvDest1
    {
        background:url(images/line_background.png);
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 10px;          
    }
    #dvDest2
    {
        background:url(images/line_background.png);
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 10px;          
    }

    #otherimgs {
        float: left;

    }
    .allcontent {
        width: 700px;
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
    .contain {
        text-align: center;

    }
    .contain img {
        margin-left: 20px;

    }
    .popup {
        position: absolute;
        top: 280px;
        right: 480px;
     }
     .popup img {
        width: 435px;
        height: 134px;

     }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideerror() {
    $('.popup').remove();
}

    $(function () {
        $("#dvSource img.one").draggable({
            revert: function () {
                $(this).delay(600);
                return true
            },
            revertDuration: 500,
            refreshPositions: true,              
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/tryagain.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1200);
            }
        });

        $("#dvSource img.one1").draggable({
            revert: function () {
                $(this).delay(600);
                return true
            },
            revertDuration: 500,
            refreshPositions: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/tryagain.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1200);
            }
        });
        $("#dvSource img.one2").draggable({
            revert: function () {
                $(this).delay(600);
                return true
            },
            revertDuration: 500,
            refreshPositions: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/tryagain.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1200);
            }
        });

        $("#dvDest").droppable({
        accept: '#dvSource img.one',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
                    $("#dvDest").html("");
                }
                ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);                  
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/greatwork.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1300);
                $( this ).hideerror();
            }
        });
        $("#dvDest1").droppable({
        accept: '#dvSource img.one1',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                if ($("#dvDest1 img").length == 0) {
                    $("#dvDest1").html("");
                }
                ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#dvDest1").append(ui.draggable);
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/greatwork.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1300);
                $( this ).hideerror();
            }
        });
        $("#dvDest2").droppable({
        accept: '#dvSource img.one2',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                if ($("#dvDest2 img").length == 0) {
                    $("#dvDest2").html("");
                }
                ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#dvDest2").append(ui.draggable);
                $("body").append('<div class="popup"><img src="images/greatwork.png"></div>'); setTimeout(function(){hideerror()},1300);                
                setTimeout(function() {
                  window.location.href = "6.htm";
                }, 1500);
                $( this ).hideerror();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="allcontent">
<div id="otherimgs">
    <img alt="" src="images/large_ball.png" />
    <img alt="" src="images/medium_ball.png" />
    <img alt="" src="images/small_ball.png" />
</div>
<div class="contain">
    <div id="dvDest"></div>
    <div id="dvDest1"></div>
    <div id="dvDest2"></div>
</div>  
</div>
<div id="dvSource">
    <img class="one" alt="" src="images/large_ball.png" />
    <img class="one1" alt="" src="images/medium_ball.png" />
    <img class="one2" alt="" src="images/small_ball.png" />
</div>
```

here i have made 3 elements droppable to their respective destination place ..i want to redirect the page to another only when all the 3 elements are dropped in their places..how to find whether the element is dropped.. can anyone help me with this??

check this fiddle for demo http://jsfiddle.net/karthikchandran/stxzqskq/3/

Comment: Create your jsfiddle with separate html, javascript and css and put images in a public server please

Comment: i have updated pls chk now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stxzqskq/5/)
try this

```
function checked()
        {
        var i = 0;
        if($("#dvDest").children("img").hasClass("dropped"))
        {
        i++;
        }
        if($("#dvDest1").children("img").hasClass("dropped"))
        {
        i++;
        }
        if($("#dvDest2").children("img").hasClass("dropped"))
        {
        i++;
        }
        console.log(i);
        if(i ==3)
        {
        window.location.href="http://google.com";
        }
        }
```

create a checked() function and call it on each droppable function
it will get redirected to the given linked as shown in fiddle demo but in fiddle it won't get redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to count the number of elements that are dropped:

```
var count = $(".dropped").length;
```

You can check this and perform an action if the expected number are dropped:

```
if (count === 3) { ... }
```